# Implementing Object Composition

Tags: game-design, java, architecture

I'm trying to structure my game object classes similar to how it is done [in this article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/).  One way to implement this strategy is discussed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546711/how-to-write-solid-pure-aggregation-composition-game-objects-in-java).

Following the strategy proposed in the linked question above, how would I control how objects are handled based on their implementations?

For example: suppose I have a base class **Item** and two subclasses **ItemPhys** and **ItemStatic**. These two subclasses both extend **Item**. **ItemPhys** implements the interface **Moveable**, but **ItemStatic** does not.

If all of the **Item**'s in my game world are stored in a single **ArrayList** of **Item** objects, how do I make it so `Item::update()` will only try to call `Item::updateMovable()` if the **Item** in question implements **Moveable**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware, so that you don't create any tight coupling you are trying to avoid by using this kind of object hierarchy.

I'd suggest you use a uniform way of updating all the components. Let all your entities (e.g. ItemMovable and ItemStatic) implement an `Item::Update()` method. Then call Update on every entity in your system. Do what you have to do for Movable ones and leave the implementation of the `ItemStatic::Update()` empty.

If you're worried about performance (i.e. it turns out to be slow specifically because you're calling too many empty methods), you could keep two lists of entities; one that contains all the entities with meaningful `Update()` method implementations, and one for the rest.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea!